# Как найти X в выражении?

Tags: javascript, математика

```js
let min = 100;
let max = 200;
let height = 1000;

// height * (x - min) / (max - min) = 4000
```

Comment: Не позориться, а почитать учебник примерно за второй-третий класс.

Comment: @Harry помоги составить формулу, если знаешь, я в 5 классе, пока сложно)

Comment: Примерно так https://img.memecdn.com/Find-x_o_160.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
height * (x - min) / (max - min) = 4000
```

Делим обе части на `height`

```
(x - min) / (max - min) = 4000 / height
```

Умножаем обе части на `(max - min)`

```
x - min = 4000 * (max - min) / height
```

Прибавляем к обеим частям `min`

```
x = 4000 * (max - min) / height + min
```

А теперь бегом! прыжками!! за учебник.

Что вы собираетесь делать в программировании с таким уровнем знаний? Сидеть на ruSO и просить написать очередную программу?